# How to add interception to an already registered component?

Tags: c#, autofac

I would like to add interception logic to classes marked by specific attributes - via type discovery - at the end of my registration logic.

My problem is that the marked types may have already been registered (for example webapi controllers), so I would like first check to make sure if the type has already been registered, and in that case "amend" the registration in some way. Unfortunately I have not found any way to get access to the `IRegistrationBuilder` through which it would be trivial to register my interceptors by calling `EnableClassInterceptors` extension method.

There are some points where this seems possible to be carried out - for example the `Activating` event or the `IRegistrationSource` interface, but in this way I had to take over a lot of responsibility, which i would like to avoid if possible.

Does anybody know if there is any trivial - or any - way of doing that in a robust way...?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to access `IRegistrationBuilder` once it has been *registered*. I looked at the source code of *Autofac* and the castle integration on the only option I can see is to work with the registration itself.

The *easiest* way to do would be to use an *Autofac* module :

```
public class XModule : Module 
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, 
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        // code inspired from RegistrationExtensions 
        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) => { /* ... */ }; 
    }
}
```

You can find the source code of the autofac dynamic proxy integration here : [RegistrationExtensions.cs (github)](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/blob/4ed145f85645bbe202e5d5081936992d23dc0e9e/src/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/RegistrationExtensions.cs)

Another option would be to refactor the way you register your types to allow more classic registrations.